# Several returns in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I want to use multiple returns in a loop in a function and get a list, but I only get one item and the rest of the code is not executed. How can this be done?

```
import random

def MyFunction():
    for i in range(5):
        return random.randint(100)

print(MyFunction())
```

Comment: A function can only have one *return value*. If you want to return a list, then you need to build a list, and return that.

Answer (score 1):

You could even try:

```
import random
def MyFunction():
    yield from random.sample(range(100), 5)

for random_number in MyFunction():
    print(random_number)
```

Or:

```
import random
def MyFunction():
    return random.sample(range(100), 5)

for random_number in MyFunction():
    print(random_number)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because function execution immediately stops after the `return` statement, i.e. the function you have written will return the value at first iteration i.e. i=0, then stop. You can either make a generator, or you can return a sequence.

```py
def MyFunction():
    result = []  #<--- Create a list to hold values
    for i in range(5):
        result.append(random.randint(0,100))   #<--- Append the values to the list
    return result  #<---- return the list

print(MyFunction())
[29, 76, 0, 7, 94]
```

On a side note, `random.randint(100)` will throw `TypeError` because it expects two values: lower limit and the upper limit.

Answer (score 0):

Once a function is returned in python, it is no longer executed. So the first item returned, it is the return value of the function. Therefore, if you want yo return a list, then return a list. This ca be done as follows:

```py
import random

def MyFunction():
    result = []
    for i in range(5):
        v = random.randint(100)
        result.append(v)

    return result

print(MyFunction())
```

Answer (score 0):

your answer is :

```
import random
stack = []
def MyFunction():
    for i in range(5):
        r1 = random.randint(0,10)
        stack.append(r1)
    return stack
print(MyFunction())
```

result :

```
[4, 0, 7, 4, 10]
```